# How can i check string value in String array?

Tags: java

I know two string values in follow type

```
String a = "Java is great!"; 
String b = "Java is great!"

if(a.equals(b))
    System.out.println("The strings are equal");
```

out put : The strings are equal

But i am using String and String[],in android project

```
String [] strarray = {"jack","Michal","Jon"};
String str = "peter jack";
```

How can i check the str values  in strarray

how to get out put is : jack help me..

Comment: What do you want to compare with what? It is very unclear.

Comment: Your question is not complete. Do you want to compare if one word from str is on strarray?

Comment: how can i search str = peter jack values in stringarray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to check if `str` is equal to a string in `strarray` so you have to cycle it.

```
for(int i = 0; i<strarray.length; i++){
   if(str.equals(strarray[i])){
      System.out.println(strarray[i]+" help me");
   }   
}
```

Comment: Maybe `strarray[i] + " help me"`

Comment: I didn't understand well his question, so if he wants to output everytime jack help is right! But i don't know, i'll update mine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
for(var i=0;i<strarray.Length;i++)
{
    if( strarray[i].equals(str) )
        // your stuff

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a String out of a String array by dereferencing it:

```
String s = strarray[0];
```

You can also compare them directly

```
if (strarray[0].equals(strarray[1])) {
  ...
```

You might find http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html a good read.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Arrays.asList(strarray).contains(str)){
    System.out.println(str +"\t Founded!");
}
```